# Unix Sed to get lines from a last occurance of a given word

Tags: unix, shell, sed

I want to get the lines from a file  from the line which contains the last occurance of a given word.

Ex:

> True, there have been some
>   changes in the plot. In the original,
>    Kane tried to buy high political
>   office for himself. In the new version,
>   he just puts politicians on his payroll.

If I give "In" then I need

> office for himself. In the new version,
>   he just puts politicians on his payroll.

Comment: You should format your example with correct line breaks, using the "code" formatting, otherwise it is not possible understand what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
grep 'yourWord' yourFile.txt | tail -n1
```

Or with sed:

```
sed -n '/yourWord/{$p}' yourFile.txt
```

Comment: Actually i need the whole text which is under the line where the pattern matches @ last

Answer (score 0):

```
$ word="In"
$ awk -vw="$word" '{s=s$0}END{ m=split(s,str,w); print w str[m]}' file
In the new version, he just puts politicians on his payroll.
```

I don't understand why there is "office for himself." though.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

As a one-liner:

```
patt=In
sed -nr "/$patt/!b;:a;\$!N;/\n.*$patt/{h;s/\n[^\n]*\$//;g;s/^.*\n//};\$!ba;p" inputfile
```

If your `sed` requires `-e`:

```
patt=In
sed -nr -e "/$patt/!b" -e ":a" -e "\$!N" -e "/\n.*$patt/{h" -e "s/\n[^\n]*\$//" -e "g" -e "s/^.*\n//}" -e "\$!ba" -e "p" inputfile
```

On separate lines:

```
patt=In
sed -nr "
    /$patt/!b
    :a
    \$!N
    /\n.*$patt/{
    h
    s/\n[^\n]*\$//
    g
    s/^.*\n//
    }
    \$!ba
    p' inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

I can print the 4th line and end of line only

My command is

sed -n '4,$p'  file